# Data binding to textblock does not update

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7.1

**I am trying to get the get the sum to update in the textblock, however I'm only able to get it updated through restarting the windows phone emulator. Why is it so?**

Code in DisplayBill.xaml

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lbTotalAmt" Text="{Binding Path=Sum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Margin="0,364,0,10" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Code in ViewModel.cs

```
    private string _Sum;
    public string Sum
    {
        get {return _Sum;}
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum"); 
        }
    } 

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify Silverlight that a property has changed.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        if (propertyName == "ToDoBills")
            UpdateSumValue();
    }

    private void UpdateSumValue()
    {
      Sum = ToDoBills.Sum(i => i.Amount).ToString();
    }
    #endregion
```

**Update

What I'm trying to do is to update the textblock everytime the listbox adds an item. so everytime a new item is added into the listbox, the textblock which display the total amount will update. So my question is how do I go about updating my textblock everytime  a new item is added into the listbox? Can anyone help me please? I tried using the binding expression below but to no avail**

```
public DetailPageBill()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the page DataContext property to the ViewModel.
        this.DataContext = App.todoViewModel;

                BindingExpression be = lbTotalAmt.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
                 be.UpdateSource();                  

    }
```

Comment: can you share a full repro?

Comment: What is a full repro?

Comment: @Keenlearner Are you getting 'Sum' value changed while debugging ?

Comment: Yes, the Sum did changed, the problem is it is only reflected after restarted the phone emulator

Comment: @Keenlearner ok, can you put your mouse over on your Textblock in xaml when Sum sets?  & check whether it shows your updated value .

Comment: when I debug the Sum = ToDoBills.Sum(i => i.Amount).ToString(); and i mouse over the Path=Sum it said null,have you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: @Keenlearner Try removing 'Path= ' & simply put 'Sum' there & check it again.

Comment: @Keenlearner Am not seeing any problem with your implementation.May be a small bug which can't be easily noticeable will be there.

Comment: I am still having the same problem whereby the value in the textblock doesn't update and only updates when I restart the emulator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26466/discussion-between-asitis-and-keenlearner)

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for your `TextBlock`'s binding:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lbTotalAmt" Text="{Binding Path=Sum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,364,0,10" Grid.Row="1" />
```

With `Explicit` no automatic update is performed. MSDN says:

> Updates the binding source only when you call the
>   UpdateSource method.

See [MSDN on UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It says PropertyChanged value was not found when I tried to change the UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: @Keenlearner Sorry, it might not be available on Windows Phone. Does it work with `Default` instead? Will edit my answer if it does...